# rmarkdown - prevent indentation in list inside a table

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

When rendering tables such as this one (using *RStudio* + `knitr`), there is unwanted indentation (see red zone in the image). How can I avoid such indentation?

I imagine there is some CSS involved, but if there was a way to even prevent `rmarkdown` from "considering" this as a list, it could simplify matters. This is needed for an R package, so heavy hacks are not really an option, but I'll gladly receive all suggestions. Thx.

### The (grid) table:

```
+------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable               | Stats / Values                     |
+========================+====================================+
| SomeVar1               | mean (sd) : 1500000.5 (288675.28)\ |
| [numeric]              | min < med < max :\                 |
|                        | 1000001 < 1500000.5 < 2e+06\       |
|                        | IQR (CV) : 499999.5 (0.19)         |
+------------------------+------------------------------------+
| SomeVar2               | 1. AAAAAA\                         |
| [factor]               | 2. BBBBBB\                         |
|                        | 3. CCCCCC\                         |
|                        | 4. DDDDDD\                         |
|                        | 5. EEEEEE\                         |
|                        | 6. FFFFFF\                         |
|                        | 7. GGGGGG\                         |
|                        | 8. HHHHHH\                         |
|                        | 9. IIIIII\                         |
|                        | 10. JJJJJJ\                        |
|                        | [ 102917 others ]                  |
+------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

---

### The rendered html table:

[image: rendered html result]

Comment: You can stop `1.` being treated as a list item by escaping it like `1\.`. To keep the line breaks between items you also need to add two spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, works like a charm! (As for the spaces - I assume you mean placing them before the `\\`, rmarkdown seems to be happy without them).